# How can I show combined "article" which has the same amount of "bids"?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, where-clause, having

I want to show the combinations of "offers" that have the same number of "bids". The Both "OID" of the combination and the number of "bids" should be output.

I know the logic I want to show which article has the same bids in combination of other article, but I don't know how I can write it down. Some code can help me to understand this.

More information about the structure of the tables "offer" and "bid". Also a "Expected result" which is shown the result

[image]

I really want to  learn SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this..

```
SELECT temp1.OID as OID1,temp2.OID as OID2,temp1.count1 as numberOfBids
FROM 
    (SELECT t1.OID,COUNT(t1.BID) as count1
               FROM bid t1 group by t1.OID) temp1
JOIN 
   (SELECT t2.OID,COUNT(t2.BID) as count2
           FROM bid t2 group by t2.OID) temp2
ON temp1.count1= temp2.count2 
AND temp1.OID <> temp2.OID
```

But it will give output as below table

```
OID1    OID2    numberOfBids
1        2          2
1        5          2
2        5          2
5        1          2
5        2          2
```

Comment: it doesnt work, can i ask what temp1 and temp2 means?

Comment: ORA-00904: "TEMP"."OID": unknown word
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: On the line of AND temp1.oid <> temp.OID

Comment: oh sry, its suppose to be temp2.oid, updated the ans

Comment: ok it works but what i want to ask how can i specify it that the oid1 oid2 is the same so it count 3 datas. If you dont know no problem

Comment: may be you can take count of rows in table bid and apply limit on final output, I tried in mysql so it didnt allow me to set limit dynamically, if you are using procedure/function then it may help you

Comment: yeah sure, ask if any doubt.. but dont forget to mark this as answer, so that it may help others to get solution